# Unable to login to Anime beta on Nexus 7

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login, authentication

For some reason, I'm unable to log into  [Anime.SE](http://anime.stackexchange.com) on my Nexus 7.  I just get a weird 400 error while attempting to log in with OAuth.  Other machines and my other Android phone work just fine.

Am I the only one seeing this?  Please advise.

[image]

Comment: You wand advice? Get a real tablet like an iPad (JK). In all seriousness, try clearing your cookies & cache then try again.

Comment: Didn't help.  Now I can't even log into the main site - I get a similar error.  Very strange.

Comment: Please visit http://anime.stackexchange.com/network-login-help and see if any step gives you issues.  I don't have a nexus to test with here, but gut feeling by symptoms is a configuration issue on the client.

Comment: Peculiar.  I visited that site, and the issue seems to have disappeared.  Thanks for pointing me that way @NickCraver; the Nexus 7 didn't have any issues according to that page.